# Python pandas cross check substring and contain relations between columns

Tags: python, pandas

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| catastrop | animal | True |
| ani | count | True |
| rows | cata | False |
| Second | rownumbers | False |
| counter | counters | True |
| column | inner | False |
|  | time |  |
|  | strong |  |
|  | kind |  |
|  | membrane |  |

A and B contain both string and substring, I want to check if column A has a value 'counter', and that value is **either having a substring in column B 'count' or is a substring of column B 'counters'**. If **any** of this satisfied, return True. (Something like combination of .isin and .str.contains). C is the output, which state whether the value of A is substring of B or A contains B. Like catastrop contain cata, so True, and ani is substring of animal so True

The initial code came into my mind is

```
list1=a1['A'].tolist()
output1=[]
for i in list1:
    output1.append(any(a1['B'].str.contains(i,regex=False)))
```

and do an or operation with column B

But if I doing it reversely, like

```
list2=a1['B'].tolist()
output2=[]
for i in list2:
    output2.append(any(a1['A'].str.contains(i,regex=False)))
```

list 2 would contain verify result about column B, rather than column A.

How could I write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is as follows:

- For `a_contains_b`, use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a string consisting of a list of values from column `B`, [`joined`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with `|` delimiter to create alternatives (so: `'animal|count|cata|rownumbers|counters|inner|time|strong|kind|membrane'`).
- For `b_contains_a`, we want to use [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) instead, since we need to feed the result back to [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to know which rows from column `A` have been matched. I.e. the result of `extractall` (+ `[0].tolist()`) will be `['ani', 'counter']`, which we use as input for `df.A.isin`.
- Finally, we use both boolean series as input for the new column. Use `|`, since we need `True` if either series contains `True`. Wrap the result in brackets and apply [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) combined with [`Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) to overwrite all `False` values in rows that have `NaN` values in column `A`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'A': {0: 'catastrop', 1: 'ani', 2: 'rows', 3: 'Second', 4: 'counter', 
              5: 'column', 6: np.nan, 7: np.nan, 8: np.nan, 9: np.nan}, 
        'B': {0: 'animal', 1: 'count', 2: 'cata', 3: 'rownumbers', 
              4: 'counters', 5: 'inner', 6: 'time', 7: 'strong', 8: 'kind', 
              9: 'membrane'}, 
        'C': {0: True, 1: True, 2: False, 3: False, 4: True, 5: False, 
              6: np.nan, 7: np.nan, 8: np.nan, 9: np.nan}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

a_contains_b = df.A.str.contains('|'.join(df.B.dropna().tolist()))

b_contains_a = df.A.isin(df.B.str.extractall(
    '('+'|'.join(df.A.dropna().tolist()) + ')')[0].tolist())

df['D'] = (b_contains_a | a_contains_b).where(df.A.notna())

print(df)

           A           B      C      D
0  catastrop      animal   True   True
1        ani       count   True   True
2       rows        cata  False  False
3     Second  rownumbers  False  False
4    counter    counters   True   True
5     column       inner  False  False
6        NaN        time    NaN    NaN
7        NaN      strong    NaN    NaN
8        NaN        kind    NaN    NaN
9        NaN    membrane    NaN    NaN
```

N.B. If you want the matching to be case-insensitive, consider using [`Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html). In the case of `str.contains` you can also make use of the parameter `case`, and set it to `False`.